# Compiling and running in java. Giving me errors

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation, ide, lwjgl

compiled my project in netbeans IDE and when I run the jar nothing happens just gives me a error occured while trying to run it. I think I found the problem just not sure how to fix it. Help please!

This is what happens when I check the jar in CMD
      C:\Users\Mac\Desktop>java -jar dist\pong.jar

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.libr
  ary.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at mw.Main.initDisplay(Main.java:36)
    at mw.Main.main(Main.java:25)

 C:\Users\Mac\Desktop>
```

When I check the manifest file it's pretty much empty:

Manifest-Version: 1.0

X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build

Comment: Looks like you are using a java native library called `lwjgl`. Not sure what it is but the `java.library.path` system property needs to point to it.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I would start by reading the (rather detailed) [installation guide](http://lwjgl.org/installation.php). Usually a good place to start when installing something.

Comment: The library is installed the way it's meant to be and the installation guide doesn't help at alllll

Comment: @MacWhite You need to do 2 things before you can use LWJGL, 1: Add the LWJGL Jars to your project. 2: Link the native dll files to your project. Have you done both 1 & 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a library and add a reference to it in your project

See [Setting Up LWJGL with Netbeans](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_NetBeans)

At a guess I'd say you are missing step 5 from [Setting Up a Project to Use LWJGL in NetBeans](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_NetBeans#Setting_Up_a_Project_to_Use_LWJGL_in_NetBeans)

> Finally, you need to tell NetBeans where the Native Libraries (i.e, DLL, JNILIB, DYLIB, SO files) are for your system so that the natives are linked when running.
>   Select the Run category and then type the following into the VM Options, replacing what is in bold to suit your system:

```
-Djava.library.path=<lwjgl-X.X path>/native/<linux|macosx|solaris|windows>
```

Update: Didn't realise you were doing it from the command prompt.  You say you are running

```
java -jar dist\pong.jar
```

You need to add the -D option so something like this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=<lwjgl-X.X path>/native/windows -jar dist\pong.jar
```

Comment: he's trying to run it using CMD, not Netbeans & hence, the dependencies aren't resolving.

Answer (score 0):

```
 when I check the jar in CMD C:\Users\Mac\Desktop>java -jar dist\pong.jar
```

You need to use the `-cp` switch while running the jar using the `java` command.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

You can easily [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java%20-cp%20&oq=java%20-cp%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.3310j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&q=java%20cp%20command&revid=1269312143&safe=off) to find more examples on how does `-cp` works.